# TFS email originator when bug is resolved

Tags: email, tfs

Will TFS automatically alert the originator of a bug when resolved or do you have to configure Alerts Editor (see TFS Power Tools) to do this?

Certaintly would be nice if this was default behavior.

Answer (score 1):

In visual studio if you go  Team > Project Alerts menu there are a few options for emailing on issue changes.

Similar question:
[TFS email notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1746061/tfs-email-notification)